# C++ polynomial class

Tags: c++, polynomials

Assignment: 
In this homework, you are going to develop a C++ class to describe and manipulate
polynomials.

complete the class declaration in the header and then implement (in a matching .cpp file)
the functions that are declared in the header file and test them to ensure they work as advertised.

The testing program supplied is very basic. You will be expected to modify it and add some (2 or more)
 tests to ensure that all aspects of the new class areexercised.

Example results from TestThePoly.cpp:

```
(1) Testing cout << A: empty
(2) Testing cin >> A':
Enter the polynomial (integer degree then double coefficients):
3 -1 2.09 -5.3 -0.98
(3) Second look at A: -1x^(3) +2.09x^(2) -5.3x^(1) -0.98
(4) Testing Polynomial B(A): -1x^(3) +2.09x^(2) -5.3x^(1) -0.98
(5) Testing Polynomial C(2, clist)': +1x^(2) +4.5x^(1) +8
(6) Testing D = C: +1x^(2) +4.5x^(1) +8
(7) Testing A == B : TRUE
(8) Testing A == D : FALSE
```

I have attempted to do this assignment many times but haven't figured it out. I looked online for something that I could help me but didn't find anything. Most of the other polynomial class problems seem to involve multiplication and such, and are at least a bit more complicated then this.  Or they are in some ways simpler/doing it differently then me.

Here is the header file

```
// Polynomial.h

#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;




class Polynomial
{

  public:
    Polynomial();
    Polynomial( int dgr, const double* clist );
    Polynomial( const Polynomial& );
    ~Polynomial();

    int setDegree(int dgr); 
    int getDegree() const;   

    const Polynomial& operator=( const Polynomial& clist);
    bool operator==( const Polynomial& clist) const;




    void printPolynomial( int dgr, const double* clist );


    double operator[]( int index ) const;
    double& operator[]( int index );

  private:
      int    degree;
      double *coefficients; // list of coefficients


};

ostream& operator<<( ostream& , const Polynomial& );
istream& operator>>( istream& , Polynomial& );

#endif
```

Here is the source file

```
// Polynomial.cpp


#include <iostream>
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

#include <cstdlib>
using std::exit;

#include "Polynomial.h"


Polynomial::Polynomial()
{
    degree        = 0;
    coefficients = 0;

}


Polynomial::Polynomial(int dgr, const double* clist)
{
     getDegree();

}

int Polynomial::getDegree() const
{
    return degree; 
}

Polynomial:: ~Polynomial()
{
    setDegree(0); 
}

int Polynomial::setDegree(int dgr)
{

    if( dgr <0 ) {
    cerr << "Error:  attempted to set a negative degree" << endl;
    exit(1);  
  } else {
    if( coefficients!=0 ) {
      delete [] coefficients;
      coefficients = 0;
      degree       = 0;
    }
    if( dgr !=0 ) {
      coefficients = new double [dgr];
      if( coefficients==0 ) {
        degree =0;
        cerr << "Warning:  unable to allocate enough space for list" << endl;
        exit(2); // this surely is reasonable.
      } else {
        degree=dgr;
      }
    }
  }
  return dgr;


}

//copy constructor 
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& clist) : degree(0), coefficients(0)
{
  if( clist.getDegree()<=0 ) {
    setDegree(0);
  } else {
    setDegree(clist.getDegree());
    for (int i=0; i< degree ; i++) {
      coefficients[i]=clist.coefficients[i];
    }
  }
}


const Polynomial& Polynomial :: operator=(const Polynomial& clist) 
{
    if ( &clist==this ) 
    {
    cerr << "Warning:  attempt to copy Polynomial onto self" << endl;
    } 
    else {
    if( clist.getDegree()<=0 ) {
      setDegree(0);
    } else {
      setDegree(clist.getDegree());
      for (int i=0; i< degree ; i++) {
        coefficients[i] = clist.coefficients[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return *this;
}

bool  Polynomial::operator==(const Polynomial& clist) const
{
    bool result=true;
  if( degree!=clist.getDegree() ) {
    result=false;
  } else {
    for(int i=0; i< degree && result == true; i++) {
      result = coefficients[i]==clist.coefficients[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}


double Polynomial::operator[]( int index ) const
{
  if( index<0 || index>= degree ) {
    cerr << "Attempt to access element outside index bounds" 
      << endl;
    exit(3); // Maybe not reasonable. 
  } else {
    return coefficients[index];
  }
}


double& Polynomial::operator[]( int index )
{
  if( index < 0 || index>= degree  ) {
    cerr << "Attempt to access element outside index bounds" 
      << endl;
    exit(4); 
  } else {
    return coefficients[index];
  }
}



ostream& operator<<( ostream& left, const Polynomial& right)
{
  if( right.getDegree() > 0 ) {
    left << endl;
    for (int i=0; i< right.getDegree(); i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j >= 0 ; j -- ){


      left << right[i] << "X^(" << j << ") " ;
  if (j > 0) 
  {     
      left << " + ";
  }

      }
    }
  } 
  else {
    cerr << "Warning:  Attempt to display empty List" << endl;
  }


  return left;
}


istream& operator>>( istream& left, Polynomial& right)
{
  int tmp;
  left >> tmp;
  if( tmp<=0 ) {
    cerr << "First value expected to be list size, > 0." << endl;
  } else {
    if( tmp!=right.getDegree() ) {
      right.setDegree(tmp);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<right.getDegree(); i++) {
      left >> right[i];
    }
  }
  return left;
}
```

Here is the testing/main file

// Prog11.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

#include "Polynomial.h"


int main()
{
  Polynomial A;
  cout << "(1) Testing `cout << A':  " << A << endl;

  cout << "(2) Testing `cin >> A':\n";
  cout << "Enter the polynomial (integer order then double    coefficients):\n\t ";
  cin >> A;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "(3) Second look at A:  " << A << endl;

  Polynomial B(A);
  cout << "(4) Testing `Polynomial B(A)':  " << B << endl;

  double clist[]={8, 4.5, 1};
  Polynomial C(2, clist);
  cout << "(5) Testing `Polynomial C(2, clist)':  " << C << endl;

  Polynomial D=C;
  cout << "(6) Testing D = C):  " << D << endl;

  cout << "(7) Testing A == B :  " << (A==B ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << endl;
  cout << "(8) Testing A == D :  " << (A==D ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")<< endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once your code works, you may consider posting a similar question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to help improve the quality of the code.

Comment: Your Polynomial destructor only needs `{ delete [] coefficients; }`.  You don't need all of that overhead of a `setDegree()` call.

Comment: Also, your `Polynomial` constructor that takes a degree and a pointer does nothing except call getDegree().  Does that look right to you?

Comment: I don't know about 'looking right' but there are two constructors, and  thus (at least to me) there is only setDegree that seems like it should go in a constructor. What else should I put in it?

Comment: It doesn't look right, but it was what looked the most right at the time. If I am not supposed to do that then what am I supposed to do?

Comment: That two argument `Polynomial` constructor sets no member variables, so what purpose did it serve?  It's almost a no-op.  Also, there are other serious memory related issues (overwrites, freeing invalid pointers, etc.) going on in your `setDegree` function at runtime.  I took your code, and under Visual Studio, crashes on a very simple 2 degree polynomial when `setDegree` is called.